# Multiple Series Line Color

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have following implementation. It is implemented and functional.  http://dojo.telerik.com/uCIhu

However, I would like to know is it possible to change line color when grade is `data[i]<60` make it red, `data[i]>=60` make it blue.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
            name: "Grading",
            color: function(point){return point.value<60 ? "red" : "blue"; },
            width: 1,
            size: 2,
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
            },
            data: [81, 91, 61, 55, 59, 43, 57, 59, 66, 65, 54, 70, 72.37]}
       ],
   seriesDefaults: {
            type: "line",
            missingValues: "interpolate"

        },
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is; please add the relevant code into your question. Don't rely on us going to an external site in order for us to help you: make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: I have added logic in my code.

Comment: Your linked Fiddle seems to do nothing at all, and the 'datavis.min.css' is 404-ing. You need to reproduce your problem at JS Fiddle, and post the code that accurately reproduces your problem in your question. Currently you've updated your question to - seemingly - change the question. *Add* information, don't remove it (unless it's utterly extraneous and unnecessary).

Comment: Please check this one http://dojo.telerik.com/uCIhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get multiple colors on one line is to apply a gradient as the stroke color.  Somewhere in your HTML you can include a hidden svg element with a gradient defined, e,g:

```
  <div style="height: 0px;">
    <svg>
      <defs>    
      <linearGradient id="theGrad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop stop-color="blue" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="blue" offset="40%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="40%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="100%"></stop></linearGradient>
    </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

NOTE: you could also just create the gradient definition in script and append it to the chart SVG.

Then use the render callback of the chart widget to apply the gradient to the line:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
       name: "Grading",
       color: function(point){return point.value<60 ? "red" : "blue"; },
       width: 2,
       size: 2,
       tooltip: {
           visible: true,
       },
       data: [81, 95, 61, 55, 59, 5, 57, 59, 66, 65, 54, 70, 72.37]}
   ],
   seriesDefaults: {
       type: "line",
       missingValues: "interpolate"     
   },
   valueAxis: {
       max: 100
   },
   render: function(e) {
       $('#chart svg g [clip-path="url(#kdef2)"] path').css("stroke", "url(#theGrad)");        
   }
});
```

Unfortunately, the kendo chart does not apply ids or classes to the various svg elements, so there is some trial and error/looking in the browser developer tools to figure out an appropriate selector.

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IXeFI)**

Also for your actual problem, you wil need to calculate the appropriate gradient stops based on your actual data range.

Comment: Wooow, interesting and perfect solution. Thanks a lot Ezanker.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible, however the code you have posted can't work:

```
function lineColor()
{
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
   if{data[i]<60}
    color="red";
   else{color="blue";}
   }
}
```

Try:

```
function lineColor(){
  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){ 
    if(data[i]<60) {color="red";}
    else {color="blue";}
  }
}
```

Alternatively just a simple ternary:

```
function lineColor(){
  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){ 
    color=data[i]<60) ? 'red' : 'blue';
  }
}
```

I'm assuming there is some identifier `color` in the scope-chain.

---

Edit:

[The official documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.color) states that one should set the `series.color` to a function,
in your case: `color: function(point){return point.value<60 ? "red" : "blue"; }`
However, I have no idea why that doesn't work in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Please refer to my jsfiddle , my question is actually more related to `kendo-chart`.

Comment: that is why I tried initially `color: function(point){return point.value<60 ? "red" : "blue"; }`, but no luck.

Comment: Me neither (although it's the answer in the doc). I also tried hex-colors (with and without `#`). I spent almost an hour on this, usually I'd say "now it's personal" and figure it out, but today I have a trunkload of other things to do. I noticed however some errors in FF 'Found function where color was expected'. One could try to load an older version of kendo. One could try it without jsfiddle.. I'm out of ideas. Hint for a folow-up/new question: Boil it down to the basic example from the doc, verify it doesn't work, *post it as stacksnippet* and ask why it doesn't work (I'll vote for that).

Comment: Check this one http://dojo.telerik.com/uCIhu , that I am working. `color function` only changes the markers not line color which I have been dealing with.

Comment: Ah, points are changing, that is at least something. Here is a thought, suppose one has `data: [70, 50, 70]`. Value 0 & 2 are above your threshold of 60, value 1 is below. What is it that you want exactly? Red from val_0 to val_1, again red from val_1 to val_2? Or red from val_0 to val_1, then blue from val_1 to val_2 (or the other way round)? Or change the line once it goes through 60 (meaning one line is blue, then red (from val_0 to val_1), then next line is red, then blue (from val_1 to val_2). I think this is important to think about, if only to further narrow down what you want exactly.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the detail is not very important at this step, what I only want to see having only a single data array returns me multi color lines.

Comment: I *think* that the answer is actually in this 'detail'. Probably you could/should pre-proces your data-array (splitting it in 2 and adding connecting points, depending on the final result you have in mind). Then plot the resulting 2 data-array's.